# Join 2 Tables with if conditions using MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: users and prov_spec_search. Am looking for an sql query to join these tables with the following conditions:

```
users Table:

id | first_name | last_name | activ_status
-------------------------------------------
6  | sudha      | dravid    |    1
7  | Gokul      | menon     |    1
13 | sujith     | nair      |    1
-------------------------------------------
```

prov_spec_search Table

```
id | inv_user_id | drafter_id | proj_status
-------------------------------------------
1  | 13          | 7          |  Ongoing
2  | 13          | 6          |    

-------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result is:

```
Need to join users and prov_spec_search tables with 2 conditions where 

users.id = prov_spec_search.drafter_id

      AND 

if project_status = Ongoing then the result proj_status should show 'Not Available'. 
if proj_status is null then should show 'Availabe'. 
if no drafters_id or no records found then from users table it should show the users name with option(proj_status) 'Available'
```

Result:

```
Name         |   proj_status   
------------------------------
Gokul Menon  |   Not Available  
sudha dravid |   Available 
sujith Nair  |   Available
```

I have started with this query:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS drafter_name,
users.id AS id,
users.activ_status,
prov_spec_search.proj_current_status
FROM users
LEFT JOIN prov_spec_search ON users.id = prov_spec_search.drafter_id
WHERE (users.activ_status ='1')
```

Comment: You don't generally need control flow (if) in queries.

Comment: without if or CASE can i achieve this result?

Comment: I thought you wanted the if in the on clause, I have posted your solution, you were almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  users.id AS id,
  CONCAT(
    users.first_name, 
    ' ', 
    users.last_name
  ) AS drafter_name,
  users.activ_status,
  IF (
    prov_spec_search.proj_current_status = 'Ongoing', 
    'Not Available', 
    COALESCE(prov_spec_search.proj_current_status, 'Available')
  ) AS proj_status
FROM users

LEFT JOIN prov_spec_search 
ON users.id = prov_spec_search.drafter_id

WHERE users.activ_status = 1
```

Comment: Getting an error actually, FUNCTION ippatent3.COALECE does not exist ippatent3 is db)

Comment: Sorry made a typo COALESCE

Answer (score 2):

With `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) AS drafter_name,
  CASE prov_spec_search.proj_status
    WHEN 'Ongoing' THEN 'Not Available'
    ELSE 'Available'
  END proj_status   
FROM users LEFT JOIN prov_spec_search 
ON users.id = prov_spec_search.drafter_id
WHERE (users.activ_status ='1')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kd7ZNTXsgbGs2uZWUFPSyM/0).
Results:

```
| drafter_name | proj_status   |
| ------------ | ------------- |
| Gokul menon  | Not Available |
| sudha dravid | Available     |
| sujith nair  | Available     |
```